# Keystone JS , what field type we can you on saving an array of objects

Tags: keystonejs

In my program I generated an array of objects which is the ImageData , Now I want to save that data to mongo Db , I have no problem with other Keys except the ImageData key because I dont know what field type  to use to be able to insert those data below which are an array of objects . What field type in keystone we could use to save those array of object example below ?. Thank you.

## Data Model , this is the model , I tried using Text array but it does not seem to work.

```
Data.add({
    name: { type: String, required: false },
    Type: { type: Types.Select, options: 'New, Used,', index: true },
    ImageData: { type: Types.TextArray },
    content: {
        brief: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 150 },
        extended: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 400 },
    },
});
```

## JSON Data that I need to save

```
  ImageData :  [ 
       { 
          "Uri":"Test.com",
          "Hash":"42e04950d6f11cd5350e3179083c7c7f",
          "Path":"/public/server/img/de29d68ab3594032bef70ead0b0d8fc2.jpg"
       },
       { 
          "Uri":"Test.com",
          "Hash":"42e04950d6f11cd5350e3179083c7c7f",
          "Path":"/public/server/img/de29d68ab3594032bef70ead0b0d8fc2.jpg"
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Did you try `ImageData: [{ Uri: String, Hash: String, Path: String }],`?

Comment: Fields must be specified with a type function @chridam

Comment: it does not work @chridam

Comment: Your example values are an array of objects, not an array of strings. Assuming you are using Keystone 4, there is no built-in type for arrays of objects.

Comment: so that field type in our model would be Sir ? so that we  can save that array of objects?

Comment: @Stennie , what would be out model ?

Comment: @Stennie , what would be the work around sir ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for so late reply.

could you try with following structure

```
Data.add({
  name: { type: String, required: false },
  Type: { type: Types.Select, options: "New, Used,", index: true },
  ImageData: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: "ImageObject", many: true }
});

ImageObject.add({
  Uri: { type: String },
  Hash: { type: String },
  Path: { type: String }
});
```

Here, `many:true` is important and your ImageData will be an array