# Field type for storing an array of objects using Mongo and Keystone JS

Tags: keystonejs

I have a model, and I need a field to store an array of objects, for which I don't know the structure.

Extend the underlying Schema with a mixed type does not work wither

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
MyList.schema.add({
ImageData: {type:Schema.Types.Mixed}, // for storing entire JS objects
});
```

## The data I wanna save

```
 ImageData :  [ 
       { 
          "Uri":"Test.com",
          "Hash":"42e04950d6f11cd5350e3179083c7c7f",
          "Path":"/public/server/img/de29d68ab3594032bef70ead0b0d8fc2.jpg"
       },
       { 
          "Uri":"Test.com",
          "Hash":"42e04950d6f11cd5350e3179083c7c7f",
          "Path":"/public/server/img/de29d68ab3594032bef70ead0b0d8fc2.jpg"
       }
    ]
```

## My Model

```
Data.add({
    name: { type: String, required: false },
    Type: { type: Types.Select, options: 'New, Used,', index: true },
    ImageData: { type: Types.TextArray },
    content: {
        brief: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 150 },
        extended: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 400 },
    },
});
```

Comment: This is at least the third time you've posted this question in the last 24 hours: [Keystone JS , what field type we can you on saving an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903062/keystone-js-what-field-type-we-can-you-on-saving-an-array-of-objects),  [Does Keystone JS supports nested schema inside of that array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916821/does-keystone-js-supports-nested-schema-inside-of-that-array). I suggest deleting the duplicates to keep the discussion focused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keystone JS , what field type we can you on saving an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903062/keystone-js-what-field-type-we-can-you-on-saving-an-array-of-objects)